# ListView scroll to selected item

Tags: android

I have a ListView with an edit text and a button below it. When I click on a listView item the keyboard appears and push up the edit text and the button. I want the list to scroll to the selected item. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: see my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29345217/1881527

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview)

Answer (score 77):

You can use ListView's [`setSelection(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) method to scroll to a row.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I used smoothScrollToPostion(position) at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int).   Important Note: I had to call it after notifyDataSetChanged() was called on the adapter.

Comment: Note, this one brings you to the position, but as in the other answer, smoothScrollToPosition actually scrolls there. Both work if you want the user to be shown something so it's a matter of how you want it to look.

Comment: how to make the listview scroll top when only one item exist?

Comment: @SilentNot This will work, you just have to call after notifyDataSetChanged() and after the changes are done in the listview. Which mean, you will have to call it in a runnable using listView.post().

Comment: @Rishabh wrong. public int scrollToFile(String fname)
    {
     int index = dirContentsAdapter.indexOf(fname);
     dirContents.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
     return index;
    } This works!

Comment: But I hate smoothScrollTo... I just need to jump to location.

Comment: The main thing is that `setSelection(int position)` is set as the last thing you do, if you do operations after that, they will wipe the `setSelection(int position)`, you fail.

Answer (score 47):

You could use ListView's [`smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) to scroll to a particular location in the list.

Comment: because of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36062, this is actually a better workaround if you want smooth scrolling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479078/smoothscrolltopositionfromtop-is-not-always-working-like-it-should/20997828#20997828

Comment: That bug, as described, seems specific to smoothScrollToPositionFromTop. Not sure it affects smoothScrollToPosition... does anyone know?

Comment: Don't know, but at time my `smoothScrollToPosition()` does not seem to work, while 'setSelection()' works; though with a jerk.

Answer (score 28):

**For a direct scroll:**

```
getListView().setSelection(11);
```

**For a smooth scroll:**

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(11);
```

**To Scroll to top**

```
getListView().setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

**Note**

> try to call it in post because sometime listview is not yet created while you calling it's method

```
getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        lst.setSelection(15);
    }
},100L);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `transcript mode`:

```
getListView().setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i was searching for, this makes the scroll instant!

Answer (score 5):

Setup a listener on your the list item being clicked, then use `View.getTop()` or `View.getBottom()` when clicked to get it's position within the parent. You can then use `ListView.scrollTo(x, y)` to scroll to the list item.

Comment: This is not working for me. If I implement your example the listView is scrolled but the selected item is not centered.

Comment: @Anita: You didn't say anything about centering... centering only takes a small modification. Simply add or reduce to the y value in proportion to to screen height.

Comment: No need to do this tho'.

Answer (score 4):

Yo can look For

> listView.setSelectionFromTop(position, distanceFromHeader);

It will position the Item at position , specified pixels below the top of listview

Comment: I need to scroll another view simultaneously while scrolling lisview. Using setSelectionFromTop on listview for scrolling blocks the UI thread which makes the scrolling of another view slow. Can you give some suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
smoothScrollToPosition(position)
```

Just increase the position of item with 1, and you will get the view of item.

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using duration gives a better user experience. Use this, with duration added. Will scroll the item in position smoothly to the top of the listview.

```
int duration = 500;  //miliseconds
int offset = 0;      //fromListTop

listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);
```

- descrease duration to make scrolling faster