# How to focus android activity to the specific item of the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am populating listview dynamically i want when activity is created it take the focus to the specific item of the listview. like in facebook app from notification it takes on the specific row of the comments.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView scroll to selected item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503133/listview-scroll-to-selected-item)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your listview extends Activity try :

```
listviewName.setSelection(positionOfItem);
```

and if your listview extends ListActivity try :

```
getListView().setSelection(positionOfItem);
```

example for my chat application, Listview must be focused at the last row
so i just put this code after message displayed

```
getListView().setSelection(getListAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
listView.setSelection(position);
```