# Get the new items added after refreshing a Listview using Pull to refresh in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I have a ListView with Pull to Refresh. After refreshing the ListView, it moves to the top. But I want to show the item added newly to the ListView. How to implement it, Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: get your item number u want to show and do scroll  programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this topic has the answer you want in addition to Ando Masahashi's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505869/1506369

Comment: For PullToRefresh List view, there is no method setSelection(int position).

Comment: listView.getRefreshableView().setSelection(int position); works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this attribute **android:stackFromBottom="true"**, because it always add new item at bottom of list view. Like following code,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>
```

And add one more thing add in your code,

```
[listView].smoothScrollToPosition([adapter].getCount() - 1);
```

Comment: Please see again my answer.

Comment: I'm using PulltoRefresh Listview. I think this works for normal list view.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `reFill` method to your adapter, for example:

```
public void reFill(List<MyData> newData){
    this.myData.clear();
    this.myData.addAll(newData);
}
```

So, after refreshing the ListView and getting new data, you call this method of adapter and set new data, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter. If you doing this, ListView doesn't move to the top.