# Expandable listview setselectionfromTop with animation and padding

Tags: android, animation, expandablelistview

I enabled animation(expand and contract) to default android'd expandable listview using this https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/blob/master/src/com/idunnololz/widgets/AnimatedExpandableListView.java.

However, the one limitation that I am facing is to move the current expanded click to the top.

I tried `setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition, 0)`

Here is the question:
   - How to add animation to bringing it to the top?
   - How to bring it to a top to a specific height. Lets say below 10px from the top.

Any pointers would be amazing.

Note: The solution should work from sdk 14 and above.

Comment: check out smoothScrollToPosition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503133/listview-scroll-to-selected-item

Comment: @Andrew I am looking into it. tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This with surely work with the library you used, i tired from my own let me know you need a sample.

```
long packedPosition = mListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition);

final long flatpostion = mListView.getFlatListPosition(packedPosition);



expandableListView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);



new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override

    public void run() {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop((int) flatpostion, HomeActivity.LIST_HEADER_HEIGHT, 200);

            }

        });

    }

}, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any pointers would be amazing.

You can use [android-advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview). The recycler view itself is a powerful widget that has a lot of features but for your question you can take a look at [MyExpandableItemAdapter.java](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_e).

> - How to add animation to bringing it to the top?

[public void scrollToPosition (int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition%28int%29)

[public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

> - How to bring it to a top to a specific height. Lets say below 10px from the top.

[public void scrollBy (int x, int y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollBy%28int,%20int%29)

[public void smoothScrollBy (int dx, int dy)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use ListView's [setSelection(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) method to scroll to a row.
- You could use ListView's [smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) to scroll to a particular location in the list.