# How to start from marked color in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have listview where say for eg: yellow color is marked in 110th position. How to display from 110th position as starting one in listview. Because user need to scroll to see the yellow marked one in 110th position.

Here is code.

```
public class TableOfContentsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public final View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

  int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if ((convertView == null) || (((Integer) convertView.getTag()) != type)) {
            convertView = createView(position);
            convertView.setTag(type);
        }
  final BaseTableOfContents node = getItem(position);
         tocView = (Node) convertView;
  ((Checkable) convertView).setChecked(okayToHighlightAnchorNode(node, position));
            convertView.setActivated(okayToHighlightTouchNodes(node, position));
        return convertView;
}
   }

 public boolean okayToHighlightTouchNodes(BaseTableOfContents candidate, int position) {
        return mTouchNodePedigree.indexOf(candidate.getNodeId()) >= position;


    }


 MainActivity: (I am clueless how to use it to display.)
//returnValue is the object of listview. 
     returnValue.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int position) {
                    TableOfContentsListAdapter adapter = (TableOfContentsListAdapter) absListView.getAdapter();
                    Log.v("scrolling","scrolling");
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    Log.v("visibleItemCount","visibleItemCount"+visibleItemCount);
                    Log.v("visibleItemCounts","visibleItemCounts"+totalItemCount);
                }
            });
```

Moreover list is showing only 0 to 9 and when scrolled, it's showing 10 to 20 and when scrolling again 20 to 30 and so on. So i couldn't take the higlighted yellow mark to display which is in some other position.

Comment: You can use `smoothScrollToPosition()` method of recyclerview, for scrolling the recycler view to random position. You can use it as `yourRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(110);`

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503133/listview-scroll-to-selected-item

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a RecyclerView instead of ListView if you can. It offers unique features like this method: `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(110);` which can help you in this case. By the way it's way more efficent in using resources than ListView.