# Listmap scroll to specified item

Tags: android, android-listview, sketchware

How do I do it so that if textviewM is clicked, the listview1 will scroll to the position of the item starting with the letter M of listmap.

[textviewM on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxZTw.png)

My code

```
textviewM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view) {
        
    }
});
```

Thank you to everyone who wants to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ListView scroll to selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503133/listview-scroll-to-selected-item)